# PHP library to read PDFs?

Tags: php, pdf

Do you know of any *free* libraries to *read* PDFs in PHP, the built in PDF functionality is only for rendering PDF output.

Answer (score 6):

Once again, Zend Framework strikes : [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) is a PDF (Portable Document Format) manipulation engine. It can load, create, modify and save documents. Thus it can help any PHP driven application to dynamically create PDF documents by modifying existing templates or generating new ones from scratch. [...]

Comment: Please note, as with most stuff in Zend Framework, Zend_Pdf is fairly easy to use stand alone without the requirement of the complete Zend Framework.

Comment: le sigh, i checked it out and it looked promising, then i tried to work with one of the sample PDFs for the project I need it for and the Zend Framework choked :(

Answer (score 3):

> Once again, Zend Framework strikes :
>   Zend_Pdf is a PDF (Portable Document
>   Format) manipulation engine

Don't forget that Zend Pdf is appliacable to use  in NON-Zend environment. Most of Zend componemts are easy pluggable to any PHP application.

Answer (score 1):

If your webserver is Unix, use the pdftotext utlity to dump the PDF to text, then display it how you want it. It's not going to have the formatting, but the text will be available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/about/) to read pdf and translate them in fpdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpLiveDocx to convert PDF, DOC, DOCX, RTF etc to TXT. For details see http://www.phplivedocx.org